# Building a Succah one suffers from in the first place?

Tags: halacha, sukkah

1. We hold that "מצטער פטור מן הסוכה" (SHUA תרמ) - one who suffers from [the conditions of] sitting in a Succah is exempt from  Succah.
2. The basic premise of the Gemora (Succah 26) this Halachah is based on that sitting in Succah should resemble sitting in his house (תשבו כעין תדורו), and if one would leave his house for that condition he's exempt from sitting in a Succah.

**Why is one allowed in the first place to build a Succah he would be suffering later**?

For example, if he knows it's going to be hot, he would install airconditioner or a couple of fans, if he knows the סכך might smell, he would be prohibited from using it etc.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is addressed by [R. Yechiel Michel Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Epstein). He begins by saying that the exemption of *mitztaer* (one who is suffering discomfort) only applies to a discomfort that happens to occur after the *succah* was built. But it is forbidden to build your *succah* in the first place in a situation that you know will cause discomfort (e.g. wind, odor, insects). He then quotes the statement of [R. Moses Isserles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) that such a *succah* (i.e. one built in a situation where you know there will be discomfort) does not even have the status of a *succah* at all (i.e. even if you do end up using it there's no fulfillment of the *mitzvah*). This is a function of the rule of *teishvu k'ein taduru* – you have to live in the *succah* as you would normally live.

R. Epstein then raises the following question: in many situations it is simply impossible to sleep in the *succah*. In hot countries insects abound, and in cold countries it is too cold. Accordingly, there should be no such thing as a real *succah* in these places, and no one there has ever fulfilled the *mitzvah* (even if they did somehow end up using the *succah*).

R. Epstein resolves this difficulty with the following explanation: As mentioned, this whole rule is a function of *teishvu k'ein taduru*. What this tells us is that in a situation where you have a choice between building a *succah* in a way that would not cause discomfort and building it in a way that would cause *discomfort* you can't build it in the way that would cause discomfort. This is because if you were building a permanent residence you wouldn't build it in a way that causes discomfort. However, if there is no way at all to build a *succah* in a way that does not cause discomfort (like for example, as mentioned, if the country is simply too cold) you can still build a valid *succah* because it is not a violation of *teishvu k'ein taduru* since even if you were building a permanent residence you would have no choice but to build it despite the discomfort.

**Thus, in sum, one cannot build a *succah* in a way that he knows will result in him suffering, unless there is no way to build a *succah* that will not result in him suffering.**

**[Aruch Hashulchan O.C. 640:8-9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&st=&pgnum=382)**

> ודווקא שבא לו הצער במקרה אחר שעשה הסוכה ובשעה שעשה שם הסוכה לא היה צער
>   זה אבל אסור לעשות סוכתו לכתחלה במקום ששם יגיע לו צער מפני הרוח או הריח
>   או במקום זבובים ופרעושים ויותר מזה כתב רבינו הרמ"א בסעיף ד' דעושה
>   במקום כזה אינה סוכה כלל ואינו יוצא בה ידי חובתו וזה לשונו ואם עשאה
>   מתחלה במקום שמצטער באכילה או בשתייה או בשינה או שאי אפשר לו לעשות אחד
>   מהם בסוכה מחמת שמתיירא מלסטים או מגנבים כשהוא בסוכה אינו יוצא באותה
>   סוכה כלל אפילו בדברים שלא מצטער בהם דלא הוי כעין דירה שיכול לעשות שם
>   כל צרכיו עכ"ל
>
> ודבריו צריכין ביאור דא"כ במדינות החמות שמצויים שם זבובים בכל מקום
>   ולהיפך במדינות הקרות שהקור גדול וכמעט מהנמנעות לישן שם נפטור את עצמינו
>   לגמרי מן הסוכה אך העניין כן הוא דהתורה אמרה תשבו כעין תדורו שתהיה
>   הסוכה כביתו ודירתו ודבר ידוע שהאדם שעושה לו דירה יחפש אחר המקום היותר
>   הגון ואם יהיה מקום הגון ומקום שאינו הגון יבחר במקום ההגון אבל אם כל
>   המקומות אינם הגונים בהכרח לעשות לו דירה איך שהוא וכמו כן בסוכה אם כל
>   המקומות אינם הגונים מפני החום או מפני הקור פשיטא שמחוייב לעשות סוכה
>   איך שיכול אמנם כשבידו לברור כגון שבמקום זה שולט הרוח או הריח רע או
>   זבובים ופרעושים ובמקום אחר אינם נמצאים מחוייב לעשות במקום שאין נמצאים
>   ואם עשה במקום שנמצאים לא יצא ידי חובתו דאין זה כעין תדורו ולכן אין
>   לעשות סוכה ברשות הרבים דאין אדם עושה דירתו ברשות הרבים אמנם בסימטא
>   נראה דמותר דאע"פ שיש לחוש לגנבים שיגנובו החפצים מ"מ הוי דירה שיכול
>   להכניסן לבית והרי גם בחצרות מצויים גנבים וזה שכתב רבינו הרמ"א דבמקום
>   דמתיירא מלסטים או מגנבים לא יצא ידי חובתו זהו כשיש חשש שיפגועו בגופו
>   דמקום כזה וודאי אינו ראוי לישן כלל אבל לא מפני גניבת חפצים

Comment: It is forbidden to build the succa, or the succa is unusable for the Mitzvah? If the former, what is the issur? It is just a hut. לפני עור? בעל תשחית?

Comment: @Yishai It's hard to argue that there's a specific *issur* in building such a hut, but those are the words the Aruch Hashulchan uses (unless you argue that he is using those words in a somewhat imprecise fashion).

Comment: @Yishai Presumably it’s forbidden in the same way that it’s forbidden to simply not build a sukkah at all

Comment: This wouldn't have been possible in his time, but without a variation of the Aruch Hashulchan's argument, you might have to look at the forecast a couple days before Sukkos and, if it's going to rain, try to find a place you can get to where it's not going to rain (or at least where it's supposed to rain less) and go there.

Answer (score 4):

The Rema in Orach Chaim 640:4 rules that if one builds a sukkah in a place where one will be unable to use it for eating, drinking or sleeping (due to discomfort or some other reason) he cannot fulfill the mitzvah in such a sukkah (even for something that he is able to use his sukkah comfortably).

Comment: This is obvious - if he's Mitztaer he's not fulfilling the Mitzvah. And this is exactly my question - why would he be allowed to build such a Succah in the first place? Like in the case of רוח מצויה - for conditions that ARE predictable why let him be Mitztaer a-priori.

Comment: That’s the point. He’s not allowed to build a sukkah in a way that he knows a priori that he will be mitztaer. The p’tur of mitztaer only applies if it’s unforseen - eg someone develops a bad cold over chol hamoed.

Comment: This is not what the answer says. It only says he cannot fulfill. Nothing that says "not allowed." *The p’tur of mitztaer only applies if it’s unforseen* is a wonderful idea - but what's the source?

Comment: I think it implies more than that. It says that one can’t eat comfortably in a sukkah, if it’s uncomfortable for sleeping. It’s as if you don’t have a sukkah at all. Inasmuch as there is an obligation to build a kosher sukkah before sukkot in order to use it on sukkot, you have not done so.

Comment: Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 135:17 quite explicitly says the (IMO fairly heavily implied) idea from this Sif. https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.135.17?with=all&lang=bi